# Can't get data from class

Tags: c#, class

I have a problem, when i put data to the public instance of the class in function =>

```
 static async Task _MainAsync()
        {
            
            Form1 info = new Form1();
            
             info.decoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(msg);
            
        }// the code is simplified
```

and when i use it in another function, the instance of the class becomes null, How can i fix it?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
           
              
  
                       await _MainAsync();
                    coin.Text = decoded.message;

                
            }
```

Comment: In your first block of code, `info` is only referenced in that method. You don't store it anywhere more permanent. You might be confused about what an instance is. Imagine there's a model of car: Toyota Prius (this is `Form1`). I buy one (`new Form1();`), and you buy one (`new Form1();`). I have a cool wrap done on mine (`myForm.Title = "hello";`), but yours is still as you bought it, as it came from the factory. Why? Well, we both have a different car.

Comment: Why is `_MainAsync` static? Perhaps it should *return* the decoded message?  Or perhaps it should not be static?  Or perhaps it should take an container object as an argument, into which it will write the decoded message.  Not sure how _simplified_ that method is.

Answer (score 0):

The instance `Form1 info = new Form1();` you created in `_MainAsync()` is local. You can't access it from outside the method.
One way you can change its property is to create the instance in `button1_Click`, send the instance as a method parameter to `_MainAsync()` change the propery in there and continue working in `button1_Click`.

```
static async Task _MainAsync(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    ...
    form1Instance.decoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(msg);
    ...
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Form1 info = new Form1();
    await _MainAsync(info);
    coin.Text = info.decoded.message;
    ...
}
```